# Differentiating with respect to odds

Tags: probability, reference-request

If the probability of an event is (for example) $3/4$, then the odds favoring the event are $3\text{-to-}1$ or $3/1=3.$

Generally if the probability is $p$ then the odds are $\omega = \dfrac p {1-p}$ and if the odds are $\omega$ then the probability is $p = \dfrac\omega {\omega+1}.$

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700531/prove-that-n-cdotx1n-1-sum-k-0nk-cdot-binomnk-cdot-xk-1/2407220#2407220) I had occasion to differentiate with respect to odds.

Let $X$ be the number of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with probability $p$ of success on each trial, with $\omega$ as above.

Let the Pochhammer symbol $(a)_b$ represent, as in the usage of combinatorialists as opposed to that of those who study special functions, the falling factorial:
$$
(a)_b = \underbrace{a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3) \cdots (a-b+1)}_{\displaystyle\text{number of factors} = b}.
$$
Then we have
$$
\frac{d^m}{d\omega^m}(\omega+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k \frac{d^m}{d\omega^m} \omega^k
$$
and hence
$$
(n)_m (\omega+1)^{n-m} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k (k)_m \omega^{k-m}
$$
and dividing both sides by $(\omega+1)^n$ we have the $m$th factorial moment
$$
(n)_m \left( \frac \omega {\omega+1} \right)^m = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k (k)_m \left( \frac \omega {\omega+1}\right)^k \left( \frac 1 {\omega+1} \right) ^{n-k}
$$
$$
(n)_m p^m = \operatorname{E}((X)_m).
$$
Is this occasion for differentiating with respect to the odds found in the literature?